# Manipulating a date in a data frame by adding +8h

Tags: r, dataframe, finance, quantitative-finance

I have a data frame column that has dates in the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. What I want to do is add +8h to every date and then change the format to `%Y-%m-%d`, so that everything at or after 16:00 will show the next day. Here is an excerpt of my data frame:

Tweets:

```
 Company,Datetime_UTC,Negative,Neutral,Positive,Volume
 AXP,2013-06-01 16:00:00+00:00,0,2,0,2
 AXP,2013-06-01 17:00:00+00:00,0,2,0,2
 AXP,2013-06-01 22:00:00+00:00,0,1,0,1
 AXP,2013-06-02 05:00:00+00:00,0,1,0,1
```

My code:

```
 Tweets$Datetime_UTC <- as.POSIXct(Tweets$Datetime_UTC, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
 Tweets$Datetime_UTC <- as.integer(Tweets$Datetime_UTC)
 Tweets$Datetime_UTC <- (Tweets$Datetime_UTC + 28800) / 86400
 Tweets$Datetime_UTC <- as.Date(Tweets$Datetime_UTC, origin="1970-01-01")
```

As you can see, I first change the date into POSIXct and then into integer, so that it can be manipulated. After that, I add 28800 (8h = 28800sec) and divide it by 86400 (24h = 86400sec). Then, I change it back into date.

Desired outcome:

```
 Company,Datetime_UTC,Negative,Neutral,Positive,Volume
 AXP,2013-06-02,0,2,0,2
 AXP,2013-06-02,0,2,0,2
 AXP,2013-06-02,0,1,0,1
 AXP,2013-06-02,0,1,0,1
```

Actual outcome:

```
 Company,Datetime_UTC,Negative,Neutral,Positive,Volume
 AXP,2013-06-01,0,2,0,2
 AXP,2013-06-01,0,2,0,2
 AXP,2013-06-02,0,1,0,1
 AXP,2013-06-02,0,1,0,1
```

Somehow, the first two rows have the wrong date, while the 3rd was correctly changed to `2013-06-02`. What can I improve so that it works correctly for every row?

Thanks in advance!! :-)

Comment: keep the object stored as POSIXct, and use a different time zone. pass the new timezones to the tz argument of `format` to get a character version.

Comment: I agree about just changing the tz. This is a better approach also because take into consideration the daylight saving time changes!

Comment: How would I do this? If I simply introduce a timezone by using e.g. `Tweets$Datetime_UTC <- as.POSIXct(Tweets$Datetime_UTC, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz="GMT+8")` the time doesn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you need to go through that whole process, would something as simple as the below work? Note I already did the `Tweets$Datetime_UTC <- as.POSIXct(Tweets$Datetime_UTC, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

```
Tweets$Datetime_UTC <- as.Date(Tweets$Datetime_UTC + 28800)

Tweets
#Company Datetime_UTC Negative Neutral Positive Volume
#1     AXP   2013-06-02        0       2        0      2
#2     AXP   2013-06-02        0       2        0      2
#3     AXP   2013-06-02        0       1        0      1
#4     AXP   2013-06-02        0       1        0      1
```

Comment: It should work, shouldn't it? However, I get the same problem as with my code. The first two rows are shown as 2013-06-01.

Comment: @hacker1337ninja it works with the sample data you provided. Does your real data differ substantially?

Comment: This is strange. I literally copied the rows from the .csv file that I am using

Comment: Maybe `Tweets$Datetime_UTC` is being read in as a factor? Alternatively it maybe restarting R might help?

Comment: Okay, because some other guys proposed it I played a little with the timezone. After just including the `tz` command into the `as.POSIXct`, it suddenly works now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use package `lubridate` and do:

```
library(lubridate)    
z$Datetime_UTC = as.Date(as.POSIXct( z$Datetime_UTC) + hm("8:00") )


> z$Datetime_UTC
[1] "2013-06-02" "2013-06-02" "2013-06-02" "2013-06-02"
```

where `z` is your data frame.

Comment: Thank you, but this somehow didn't work for me. It shows the same result as my table with the actual outcome